# Getting Soap Body from Web Service Consumer

Tags: soap, mule

I have a web service consumer in a flow and simply want to extract the XML contained in the soap envelope to be put on the outbound vm queue. How can I accomplish that in a flow, I have shown a sample of the soap message;

```
<ws:consumer-config name="WS_Connector"
            connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" wsdlLocation="orderService.wsdl"
            service="OrderService" port="OrderServiceWS"
            serviceAddress="http://ws-orders.com?responseTimeout=60000"
            doc:name="Web Service Consumer" />

            <flow name="mainFlow">  
                <vm:inbound-endpoint path="request.queue"/>
           <ws:consumer config-ref="WS_Connector"
            operation="orderTShirts" doc:name="TShirt Service Consumer">
           </ws:consumer>
        <!-- Get Just the XML Payload without the Soap Envelope 
          for the vm outbound queue
             <tshirt xmlns="http://www.webservice.order-service">
                  <size>17</size>
                       <color>red</color> 
              </tshirt>
            -->
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="response.queue"/>
      </flow>



                      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

                  <soap:Body>
                    <tshirt xmlns="http://www.webservice.order-service">
                       <size>17</size>
                       <color>red</color> 
                       </tshirt>
                   </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

The web-service-consumer is designed to only accept the body/operation part of the XML document and will produce body/operation in response.
Pls go through the dataweave document :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/web-service-consumer

What you can do here use XSLT transforer or DataWeave to add your soap envelope after your `<ws:consumer/>` in the response  something like following example :-

```
<!-- your code above -->
    <ws:consumer config-ref="WS_Connector" operation="orderTShirts" doc:name="TShirt Service Consumer"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="XML to JSON" >
                <dw:input-payload doc:sample="ListInventoryResponse.xml"/>
                <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
    %output application/xml
    %namespace ns0 http://mulesoft.org/tshirt-service
    %namespace soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
    ---
    soap#Envelope : {

    soap#Body:payload

    }]]></dw:set-payload>
      </dw:transform-message>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I solved it with a dom to xml transformer. I was looking to remove the soap envelope not add it.

Comment: You said here **"simply want to extract the XML contained in the soap envelope to be put on the outbound vm queue"** which means you want to extract the response contained in Soap envelope (That means response with Soap envelope) ... otherwise you will always get response after `<ws:consumer/>` without Soap envelope and header as web-service-consumer is designed to work without Soap envelope and header... this feature is by default ... only you need to transform it into xml

Answer (score -2):

The solution I found is quite simple

```
     <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="SOAP Response to XML" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/xml" outputEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```